Exporting x and y data to adjacent columns in file.txt
The following code draw three curves:
import random
import numpy as np
import cmath
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


z_points=np.array([0, 1, 2])
for z in z_points:
    y_points=[]
    x_points=np.array([0, 1, 2])
    for x in x_points:
        y=2*x+z
        y_points.append((y))
    plt.plot(x_points, y_points,'bo-', markersize=5)

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.grid()

plt.grid(True, which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='1', color='black')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='1', color='gray')
plt.xlim([0, 5])
plt.ylim([0, 10])
plt.legend(['z[0]','z[1]','z[2]'])
plt.show()

I am trying to export these multiple curves x and y data to txt file.txt such that they are adjacent with columns to be like that in the file.txt:
x1    y1    y2    y3

0     0     1     2 

1     2     3     4

2     4     5     6


Use numpy function np.savetxt()
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

z_points = np.array([0, 1, 2])
data = []

for z in z_points:
    y_points = []
    x_points = np.array([0, 1, 2])
    for x in x_points:
        y = 2*x + z
        y_points.append(y)
    plt.plot(x_points, y_points, 'bo-', markersize=5)
    data.append(y_points)

# Transpose the data and insert x_points at the beginning
data = np.array(data).T
data = np.insert(data, 0, x_points, axis=1)

# Save to text file
np.savetxt('file.txt', data, fmt='%d', delimiter='\t', header='x1\ty1\ty2\ty3')

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('f(x)')
plt.grid()

plt.grid(True, which='major', linestyle='-', linewidth='1', color='black')
plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid(True, which='minor', linestyle=':', linewidth='1', color='gray')
plt.xlim([0, 5])
plt.ylim([0, 10])
plt.legend(['z[0]','z[1]','z[2]'])
plt.show()

file.txt:
x1  y1  y2  y3
0   0   1   2
1   2   3   4
2   4   5   6

